# py.test: Show local variables in Jenkins

Tags: python, django, jenkins, pytest, sentry

Up to now we call `py.test` via Jenkins.

If a test fails, we see the usual stacktrace like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/src/foo/bar/tests/test_x.py", line 36, in test_schema_migrations
    errors, out))
AssertionError: Unknown output: ["Migrations for 'blue':", ...]
```

It would be really great, if I could see local variables like in the django debug page (See https://djangobook.com/wp-content/uploads/figure2_3a.png).

.... But they should only be visible if I want to see them. I guess this means I need a different format than text. Maybe HTML?

Is there a way to enable this?

I never used the tool Sentry. But AFAIK this can display nice tracebacks with local variables.

Comment: moidule `cgitb` can help - insert `cgitb.enable(format='text', context=12)` at the top of the module

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian yes this could work. But this would bloat the default impression. I want to see the local variables only sometimes. If I see them always, then daily work gets a bit harder ...

Comment: Like using a dropdown as on the djangobook page? Plain text won't do it, don't know what service like that exists...

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian you call it "service". I think you need two parts: One part which creates a traceback with more detailed information and a second part which renders this as HTML.

Comment: have not tried this, but `cgitb.enable(format='html')` may give you what you want. Give it a try.

Comment: @georgexsh `cgitb.enable(format='html')` is a good idea.

Comment: @guettli I guess what you desired is kind of UX optimization when Jenkins display traceback: collapse local variables part by default, expand on demand.

Comment: @guettli maybe you could run tests with `pytest -l`, then generate two versions of the test report: one with locals, another one filter out locals port, access as you want. but unfortunately, I dont have Jenkins at hand cant test this idea.

Comment: @georgexsh Jenkins is scriptable, you idea (create two versions of the test report) would work.

Comment: @guettli hope this is useful to you. ps: have answered quite a few of your questions recently :)

Answer (score 10):

Use `-l`/`--showlocals` option:

> ```
> pytest --showlocals # show local variables in tracebacks
> pytest -l           # show local variables (shortcut)
> ```

example:

```
    def foo():
        a = 1
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

a          = 1

test_foo.py:8: AssertionError
```

see [more details in the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing).

Comment: I want to see the local variables only sometimes. If I see them always, then daily work gets a bit harder ..

Comment: okay, but I have this option for all my CIs, which is very useful.

Comment: @guettli, it can either be captured or it can't be. How would one define sometimes without changing some config before running the tests?